# Who owns a video recording of a sporting event?

Tags: copyright, civil-law, australia, recording

A colleague of mine recorded an sporting event on his mobile phone.  He then forwarded the video to me.  I entered the video in a competition on a television program.  The video won and the prize is $1000 Australian dollars.

I notified the colleague of the award and suggested that we will split the prize money.  However he wants the full $1000 prize, claiming he is the rightful owner of the video.

Is he the owner of the video?  And is he entitled to the prize?

Comment: Yeah, no. If I send you an artwork, do I suddenly have no copyright claim to it? If it was a professional sporting event, there even may be a claim to copyright by the sporting association.

Comment: Morning M Kennedy thanks for your feed back , I think copyright is not a issue here copyright laws apply more to people's artistic and creative works. this was a 10 sec phone video at a local football match.

Comment: Unfortunately copyright extends to any media you create. So the 10 seconds video counts. He's being rather mean to you, but the law is on his side.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks: copyright extends to works, not media in general. It must surpass a threshold of originality, which is not very high though.

Answer (score 3):

Pay him the $1,000: it's his video so it his money.

If you're lucky he won't sue you for copyright infringement. If you're very lucky he won't sue the TV station for copyright infringement (because they would immediately sue you under the indemnity clause you undoubtedly signed when you submitted a video you said you owned but didn't). If you're extremely lucky he might buy you a beer.